# How to get the difference between two currents by using only analogue circuitry?

Tags: differential

If I have two current sources, producing currents I1 and I2, respectively, getting the sum of the two currents is easy—just connect both sources to one end of a wire and the currents will be forced to go through it in the same direction, meaning that they sum up to I1 + I2. But is there some way to instead get the difference between the two currents to flow through the wire, i.e., I1 - I2, without involving AD and DA converters and digital electronics?

If of any interest, the way I1 and I2 are generated is by connecting a node with electric potential V to two conductors, with conductances C1 and C2, respectively, where I1 = V * C1 and I2 = V * C2. There is then a node with the potential 0 that can be used to create the voltage V over the two conductors, but which doesn't have to be connected directly to the conductors.

Comment: Just use exactly the same method - join the wires and hey presto, the net result is the difference (providing you have a current path for the result).

Comment: Why do you think EEs use circuit diagrams instead of incomprehensible sentences to describe things?

Comment: Can you use the circuit diagram editor to include a circuit diagram in your question please?

Comment: Who is the close vote fellow? What goes on in their mind?

Comment: If both currents from to a common "ground" then passing each through equal sense resistors R1 & R2 will produce voltages I1.R1 and I2.R2. The difference in potential at the "top" of the sense resistors will be proportional to the difference in currents. I-delta = Vdelta/R

Comment: If you have two ideal current sources, the answer is easy: connect them in anti-parallel. But what you have in your circuit is so different from ideal current sources that thinking of them like current sources is not going to help you.

Answer (score 1):

An instrumentation operational amplifier (IOA) can be used to measure the voltage difference between two nodes, in this case, the voltage drop across a shunt resistor. Assuming that you have a positive and a negative voltage rail, the "positive and negative" current can then be worked out by diving the output voltage by the IOA's gain and then by the shunt resistance.

*NOTE: The following circuit would not be applicable for measuring "negative" current*.
$$V_{out} = (1+\dfrac{2R_1}{R_{gain}})\dfrac{R_3}{R_2}(V_2 - V_1)$$

[image: Circuit_1]
[Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instrumentation_amplifier)

Here is a working example. As you can see, the calaculated current has a very correlation with the actual current flowing through the shunt resistor \$R_1\$. The IOA gain is set to \$3\dfrac{V}{V}\$ and the shunt resistor equals \$10m\Omega\$.

[image: Circuit_2]

Answer (score 0):

If the current is AC and in phase, this can be done simply with a transformer with three windings: connect one of them backwards. The field induced will cancel the field in the forward-wired winding, so the current induced in the third winding will be the difference.

This principle was used by "synchro" servo systems: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synchro